# Symfony user role not read

Tags: php, symfony

i try :

in console :

```
php app/console fos:user:promote grek admin
Role "admin" has been added to user "grek".

if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) die('ok');
```

this is not show why ?

i log off, log in and same situtation

```
var_dump($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());

i>protected</i> 'roles' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=4)</i>
      0 ADMIN'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
      1 OWNER'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
      2 TESTER'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>


 $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
  var_dump($user->getRoles());

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'ROLE_USER' (length=9)
```

why $user->getRoles() give only one ?

when i add 
php app/console fos:user:promote grek ADMIN
php app/console fos:user:promote grek ROLE_ADMIN
php app/console fos:user:promote grek admin

then check - i dont have role in if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted

And somethink else :

```
php app/console fos:user:promote grek test
Role "test" has been added to user "grek".
php app/console fos:user:demote grek test
User "grek" didn't have "test" role.
```

What is this ?

Comment: Try `php app/console fos:user:promote grek role_admin`

Comment: this not change situation is same.

Answer (score 1):

You have granted the user the role `ADMIN`, when it should be `ROLE_ADMIN`

**UPDATE**

You can solve your problem either running

`php app/console fos:user:promote grek role_admin`

Or changing

`if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) die('ok');`

to

`if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ADMIN')) die('ok');`

Comment: It helps to be even a bit more explicit with answers - i.e. reference the particular line of code that your answer applies to and provide an example of the corrected syntax.